# MVC PHP: How to minimize redundant data when nesting views?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have my own MVC framework, very similar to CodeIgniter.

Any view is loaded as loadView($view_name, $paramaters);

Lets say there are 3 Views, A,B & C.

- A loads 5 B's and B in turn loads 5 another C's
- Each C has a form where we need to display logged in username and logged in profile pic
- So we're passing 5*5 = 25 times the same username and profile pic of logged in user

That's bad! We cannot use SESSION or another GLOBAL variable inside a view. What would be the best solution for this to reduce this redundancy?

Regards,
Sanket

Comment: Show us some view code. I don't see anything wrong with what youre doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making new variables are you? you're just passing existing variables around. Or you should be anyway. Nothing inherently wrong with that. Really.

Answer (score 0):

it shouldn't matter memory wise, but setting the data that many times can clutter your code. what I have done before is, instead of having the nested views hold their own data, have your parent view render the child views so that all views can access the data held in the parent. in my view class i allow for either/or. you can add child views which can hold their own data and render themselves, or you can add child templates, which are rendered by the parent view and can access the parent data.